# ¿Cómo obtener el nombre del archivo seleccionado en un input type="file"?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estoy intentando hacer unos inputs tipo `file` en mi web pero no consigo que cuando se seleccione un archivo se vea cual es, he intentado seguir el ejemplo de aquí: https://tympanus.net/codrops/2015/09/15/styling-customizing-file-inputs-smart-way/

```css
.inputfile {
 width: 0.1px;
 height: 0.1px;
 opacity: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: -1;
}
.fileUpload {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 10px;
}
.fileUpload input.upload {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
}
```

```html
<input id="image1" type="file" class="inputfile hidden-xs hidden-md" value="image1" name="image1" required />
<label for="image1" class="my-btn btn-danger"><center>Archivo 1</center></label><br>
```

Lo que quiero es que cuando yo seleccione un archivo en vez de poner "Archivo 1" ponga el nombre del archivo y no sé como hacerlo, he probado de copiar el código js que hay en esa web pero cuando lo pongo deja de funcionar del todo.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es simplemente el nombre del fichero entonces lo puedes obtener directamente del `input` accediendo al atributo `name` del primer fichero cargado en el `input`:

```
document.getElementById('image1').files[0].name;
```

Sin embargo, si intentas obtener la ruta en la que se encuentra dicho fichero, puedes intentarlo realizando `this.value`. Sin embargo, como puedes observar, te devuelve una ruta que no es la real del archivo y te lo sustituye por un `fakepath`. Esto se debe a que por motivos de seguridad no se agrega la ruta en la que el usuario tiene almacenado el fichero.

Tu ejemplo modificado:

```js
document.getElementById('image1').onchange = function () {
  console.log(this.value);
  document.getElementById('fichero').innerHTML = document.getElementById('image1').files[0].name;
}
```

```css
.inputfile {
 width: 0.1px;
 height: 0.1px;
 opacity: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: -1;
}
.fileUpload {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 10px;
}
.fileUpload input.upload {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
}
```

```html
<input id="image1" type="file" class="inputfile hidden-xs hidden-md" value="image1" name="image1" required />
<label id="fichero" for="image1" class="my-btn btn-danger"><center>Archivo 1</center></label><br>
```

Comment: Muy útil la forma de acceder al atributo desde el input. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

```css
.inputfile {
    width: 0.1px;
    height: 0.1px;
    opacity: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
}
.fileUpload {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 10px;
}
.fileUpload input.upload {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
}
```

```html
  <input id="image1" type="file" class="inputfile hidden-xs hidden-md" value="image1" name="image1" required />
 <label for="image1" class="my-btn btn-danger"><span>Archivo 1</span></label><br>
    <script>
                   'use strict';

;( function ( document, window, index )
{
    var inputs = document.querySelectorAll( '.inputfile' );
    Array.prototype.forEach.call( inputs, function( input )
    {
        var label    = input.nextElementSibling,
            labelVal = label.innerHTML;

        input.addEventListener( 'change', function( e )
        {
            var fileName = '';
            if( this.files && this.files.length > 1 )
                fileName = ( this.getAttribute( 'data-multiple-caption' ) || '' ).replace( '{count}', this.files.length );
            else
                fileName = e.target.value.split( '\\' ).pop();

            if( fileName )
                label.querySelector( 'span' ).innerHTML = fileName;
            else
                label.innerHTML = labelVal;
        });

        // Firefox bug fix
        input.addEventListener( 'focus', function(){ input.classList.add( 'has-focus' ); });
        input.addEventListener( 'blur', function(){ input.classList.remove( 'has-focus' ); });
    });
}( document, window, 0 ));</script>
```

Comment: Presiona ejecutar y pruebalo. Saludos

Comment: Por sierto pon span en tu html