# Manipular texto mostrado por input file multiple

Tags: javascript, html

Consulta breve...

Me encuentro trabajando en un formulario de reporte donde se deben subir imágenes, para tal efecto tengo:

```
<input type="file" multiple>
```

Mi duda puntual es:

¿Se puede manipular de alguna forma para que cuando se seleccione un solo archivo diga `1 archivo` (como lo hace cuando se seleccionan varios) en vez de que muestre el nombre de ese único archivo?

Comment: Por favor, incluye el código y los mensajes de error relevantes a tu pregunta. Para ello, edita la pregunta y pega esto como texto (le puedes dar formato en el editor).

Comment: Hola, considero irrelevante el agregar código a la pregunta porque lo único que tengo es actualmente un input file y listo... No tengo ni por donde empezar o terminar para probar lo que estoy planteando por ende, no puse nada de códigos arriba o sino sería un formulario que no tendría relevancia con mi duda específica... Saludos

Comment: No sabemos a qué se refiere el "manipular de alguna forma", no sabemos en dónde deseas que se muestre `1 archivo`, etc. Los problemas de código necesitan código. Saludos! :)

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿Cómo obtener el nombre del archivo seleccionado en un input type="file"?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/41373/c%c3%b3mo-obtener-el-nombre-del-archivo-seleccionado-en-un-input-type-file)

Comment: Si no sabes por dónde empezar, empieza por la documentación: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/File/Using_files_from_web_applications

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se podria, pero no de una forma directa en el input. Sino con codigo javascript, ocultando el input y mostrando otros elementos en su lugar.

Por ejemplo:

```js
function abrir(id) {
    var file = document.getElementById(id);
    file.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click', {
        view: window,
        bubbles: true,
        cancelable: true
    }));
}
function contar(elem, idGlosa) {
    var glosa = document.getElementById(idGlosa);
    if(elem.files.length == 0) {
        glosa.innerText = "Ningun archivo seleccionado";
    } else {
        glosa.innerText = elem.files.length + " archivos";
    }
}
```

```html
    <label for="archivo">Subir archivo</label>
    <button type="button"
            onclick="abrir('archivo')">Escoger archivos</button>
    <input type="file" multiple
           id="archivo" name="archivo"
           onchange="contar(this, 'glosaArchivos')" style="display: none">
    <span id="glosaArchivos">Ningun archivo seleccionado</span>
```

Comment: Probando desde aquí ya me dice que me servirá super para mi proyecto.... Mil gracias Klaimmore :D